# Is there a way to make a dictionary value equivalent to set element in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I am new to Python and I am using Python 3.7. So, I am trying to make my dictionary value equal to set i.e., `dictionaryNew[kId] = setItem`. So basically I want each `kId` (key) to have a corresponding row of set as its value. I am using **set** because **I don't want duplicate values in the row.**

**This is a piece from my code below:**

```
setItem = set()
dictionaryNew = {}

for kId, kVals in dictionaryObj.items():
    for index in kVals:   
        if (index is not None):
            yourVal = 0
            yourVal = yourVal + int(index[10])
            setItem.add(str(yourVal))
            print(setItem) #the output for this is correct

    dictionaryNew[kId] = setItem
    setItem.clear()

print(dictionaryNew)
```

When I print `setItem`, then the result is printed correctly.

**Output of `setItem`:**

```
{'658', '766', '483', '262', '365', '779', '608', '324', '810', '701', '208'}
```

But when I print `dictionaryNew`, the result is like the one displayed below.

**Output of `dictionaryNew`:**

```
{'12': set(), '13': set(), '17': set(), '15': set(), '18': set(), '10': set(), '11': set(), '14': set(), '16': set(), '19': set()}
```

I don't want the output to be like this. Instead, I want the dictionary to have a row of set with its values. But this is just printing empty set when I try to print `dictionaryNew`. So what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share `dictionaryObj` structure ? I'm not sure to understand what it is

Comment: And why do  : youvalue + 0 each time  ?

Comment: `dictionaryObj` has key:value pairs. So basically it has a string as a key and set of strings as value. Also, I am using 0 every time because there is delta encoding at index[10]. So in order to decode it, I am using this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same `setItem` instance all along, if you remove `setItem.clear()` you'll see that every key points to the same value.

You may create a new `set()` at each iteration

```
dictionaryNew = {}
for kId, kVals in dictionaryObj.items():
    setItem = set()
    for index in kVals:   
        if index is not None:
            setItem.add(str(int(index[10]))) # the temp sum with 0 is useless

    dictionaryNew[kId] = setItem
```

Using dict-comprehension this it equivalent to

```
dictionaryNew = {
    kId: {str(int(index[10])) for index in kVals if index is not None}
    for kId, kVals in dictionaryObj.items()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the issue. I didn't see it like that.

Comment: @MeharFatimaKhan You're welcome, could you just give an example of what dictionaryObj is ? Maybe I could write it simplier

Comment: This is an example of `dictionarObj`'s structure. A string as key and a set of strings as values.

'723': ['1979', '4225', '780', '7264'], '752': ['6060', '758', '93', '749'], '712': ['345', '59', '11684', '2006'], '771': ['13770', '1148', '15198', '15184']

Comment: @MeharFatimaKhan I don't understand what you try to access with index[10] becaus index is jsut ONE char at this moment

Answer (score 1):

you are removing all the elements from your `set` at this line `setItem.clear()`

you can use a dictionary comprehension to convert your list elements to set:

```
dictionaryObj = {k: set(v) for k, v in dictionaryObj.items()}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.